# Show ajax spinners for many ajax calls.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently I'm showing the spinners, using ajax setup method call:

```
(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: showLoader,
        complete: hideLoader,
        error: hideLoader
    });
})();
```

This is working fine, but the problem now happening is, when many ajax call happens, `complete` is closing the loader!.

Is there any easy way to handle this?

Comment: AFAIK, `complete` will trigger as soon as one of the ajax calls is complete and not ALL. You're after hiding the spinner for only those requests that are complete?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at jQuery's [.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [.ajaxStop](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxStop) methods.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  // show your loader
});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  // hide your loader
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is keep a counter of how many ajax calls are going, when a call is made increment, when a call is finished de-incriment and then, in the `hideLoader` function just check the counter, if it's higher then `0` don't hide it.

Answer (score 0):

There `DOM` events in jQuery which bind ajax starting and ajax ending events. Use

```
.ajaxStart();
.ajaxStop();
```

to show your loader in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.ajaxStop()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/), which is called when all Ajax calls have executed,

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  //call hideLoader here
});
```

Comment: Whats the time frame does jQuery checks this, from the docs:  *jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers the ajaxStop event*

Comment: There isn't a time frame, it depends on the amount of your requests, and the client.  Heavily varies.